# Pdf figures not shown in html files produced by Rmarkdown when open with Firefox or Chrome

Tags: html, r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown

I want to insert a pdf figure into the html file produced by Rmarkdown. Here is my `test.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "knit include_graphics"
author: "D Li"
date: "4/21/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r out.width=800}
knitr::include_graphics("/Users/dli/Dropbox/UFL/SFL/Doc_beta_div/ecoregions_all.pdf")
sessionInfo()  
```
````

Here is my session info:

```
## R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
## Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
## Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4
## 
## locale:
## [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] backports_1.0.5      magrittr_1.5         rprojroot_1.2       
##  [4] tools_3.3.2          htmltools_0.3.5      yaml_2.1.14         
##  [7] Rcpp_0.12.10         stringi_1.1.2        rmarkdown_1.4.0.9001
## [10] knitr_1.15.19        stringr_1.2.0        digest_0.6.12       
## [13] evaluate_0.10
```

Then use the `knit` button in Rstudio Version 1.0.136, I get a `test.html` file. The inserted figure show in the RStudio viewer panel and in Safari. But it won't show in Chrome or Firefox. Does any one have the same problem? How should I solve it?

Thanks.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is a **knitr** issue when the chunk option `out.width` is present, and I just [fixed it](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/f0be08392b5f1471cb8a38ae661ca962a3d39164) on Github. You may `devtools::install_github('yihui/knitr')`.

Without `out.width`, Pandoc writes out the PDF image `![](foo.pdf)` using the `<embed>` tag, which works in all major browsers, but when `out.width` is specified, **knitr** will use the HTML syntax `<img src="foo.pdf" />` to write out the image, and it does not work in Chrome or Firefox. The way that I fixed this issue was to change the tag to `<embed>` like what Pandoc does.

Comment: What is your `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`? I'm using 1.17.2, the one that RStudio ships with it. If you have installed a higher version of Pandoc, you probably want to remove it.

Comment: It works now with Chrome and Firefox. Thanks! However, the <embed> frame is so obvious (and ugly).

Comment: It is interesting that Safari, but not Chrome and Firefox, can show the pdfs that inserted as images. Converting pdf into png can solve the frame issue, but still not ideal. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there a better way in 2020?